# Set cookie on Startup (MVC .Net Core)

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-core, cookies

I am converting a VB project on the .NET Framework to C# .Net Core 2.2

In the VB project the cookie is set in the **Global.asax.vb**:

```
Private Sub MvcApplication_BeginRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.BeginRequest
    ' Redirect non-www. to www.
    If Not Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www") AndAlso Not Request.Url.IsLoopback Then
        Dim builder = New UriBuilder(Request.Url)
        builder.Host = "www." & Request.Url.Host
        Response.StatusCode = 301
        Response.AddHeader("Location", builder.ToString)
        Response.End()
    End If

    //Cookie set here
    If HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("CH") Is Nothing Then
        Dim myCookie = New HttpCookie("CH")
        myCookie.Values("DeviceId") = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString()
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(45)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie)
    End If
End Sub
```

Here are my functions to return the cookie in C# (Controller and httpContext based):

```
    public static string getUserDeviceId(ControllerBase controller)
    {
        return controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["DeviceID"];
    }

    public static string getUserDeviceIdFromContext(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        return context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["DeviceID"];
    }
```

I would be getting the 'id' by using the following:

```
string userDeviceId = BettingService.getUserDeviceId(this);
string userDeviceId = BettingService.getUserDeviceIdFromContext(_httpContext);
```

How would I setup this cookie in .Net core C#  the same way? I am presuming I will be using somewhere in the Startup.cs?

Comment: No, Startup configures your application. If you want to do something for each request, you should write middleware that does this.

Comment: Hi, is there an example for this somewhere.

Comment: See the linked duplicate.